# MOSS 2007: jquery can't access web methods from custom web parts

Tags: 2007, web-part, web-application

I have custom web parts on MOSS 2007 that uses jquery to call my custom web methods. I have been checking my MOSS 2007 Web Application on Firefox with Firebug and on the Console Tab it says 401 errors for my web methods.

Any links or ideas that could allow my web methods to be accessed?

Comment: Custom web services or the OTB SharePoint web services?

Comment: Custom Web Services... I'll be updating my post to avoid others from being confused. Thanks!